# jQuery SpriteSpin zoom image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, zooming

I use JavaScript library SpriteSpin http://spritespin.ginie.eu/ to view the 3D image, is there any way to add a button to zoom the picture?

I know that there is a module http://www.cmz.ru/html/static/spritespin-master/page/docs/spritespin.mod-zoom.html but i dont know how to use it.

Solve some similar problem?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you define your own button you can zoom in and out with this:

```
$('#myZoomButton').click(function() {
    $("#mySpriteSpin").spritespin('api').toggleZoom();
})
```

For some reason this is not documented in the [api description](http://spritespin.ginie.eu/docs/spritespin.api.html), as well as `.toggleFullscreen()`, `.fullscreenElement()`, `.fullscreenEnabled()`, `.requestFullscreen()`, `.exitFullscreen()`.